# Trying to get property of non-object error in Laravel when assigning an ID to a variable

Tags: php, laravel

1. I'm getting the row in the following code :

```
$grpusrow = DB::table('grpusrs') 
                       ->where('group_id', $id)
                      ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                      ->get();
```

2. And then getting the ID in this line :

```
$grpusrid = $grpusrow->id;
```

3. I receive the following error on the line in number 2 :

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `var_dump($grpusrow)` check this

Comment: Actually, putting ->first(); instead of ->get(); did work

Comment: `get()` retrieves a collection of objects, so you need to iterate through it. Using `first()` retrieves a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->get()` will always return multiple objects at once. You're simply not telling it which index of `$grpusrow` to get the ID from.

```php
$grpusrows = DB::table('grpusrs') 
                    ->where('group_id', $id)
                    ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                    ->get();

foreach ($grpusrows as $grpusrow) {
    dump($grpusrow->id);
}

// Or

$grpusrow = DB::table('grpusrs') 
                    ->where('group_id', $id)
                    ->where('user_id', $u_id)
                    ->first();

dump($grpusrow->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 2 solutions:

1. If you want a unique row in return (with a primary key in arguments for example), you should try ->first() instead of ->get().
2. The problem is the using of where clauses, I think it works with array when you want more than one where clause, try like this :

`->where([['group_id', '=', $id],['user_id', '=', $u_id]])->get();`  ( or first() )